# Uncaught TypeError: angular.module is not a function at

Tags: angularjs

This is in `app.js`:

```
var angular = angular.module('ngApp', ['ngRoute']);
angular.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/companies.html',
        controller: 'companies'
    })
    .........
});
```

This is in `companies.js`:

```
angular.module('ngApp').controller('companies', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    .........
}]);
```

This is in `index.html`:

```
<head>
    <title>Basic demo</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/Controllers/companies.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>
```

I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: angular.module is not a function
>       at companies.js:1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Consider changing your tag. `angular` is for Angular v2+. `angularjs` is for Angular v1. That will ensure that the appropriate people see your post.

Comment: I just shortened it, sorry for confusion. In reality: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>`

Comment: Oops, got it now. Thanks for this @DeborahK

Comment: @SamKirklandWA Try changing the variable name from `angular` (first line of the posted script in app.js) to something else like `myApp`. The problem should be that using `angular` as variable name, you override the original `angular` object (the one that it's exposed from AngularJS libraries)

Comment: @lorenzomontanari, `companies.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: myApp.module is not a function`

Comment: @SamKirklandWA you changed the wrong one.  lorenzo meant the variable you are defining.  var myApp = angular.module(.....)  You will also then need to change to myApp.config on the next line as that is your new variable name for your app.

Comment: @Dillon, thanx for showing, but I did what he pointed out: `var myApp = angular.module('ngApp', ['ngRoute']); myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {`

Comment: @SamKirklandWA and it is still not working?  Are you wrapping your app.js and other controllers in an IIFE?

Comment: @Dillon, how to do that? Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Can you put all of the relevant code inside of plnkr.co?  Then it would be easier to tell what is wrong.

Comment: @SamKirklandWA see code block below.  Basically wrapping your js file in a function to create scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use a variable called angular. Think what causes that variable to exist. That is found in the angular.js script which must then be included first.

At the time your angular code runs, angular does not exist yet. This is an error (see your console window of Dev Tools ). Kindly use same version of Angular file and angular-route !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've overwritten `angular` object in `app.js` file:

```
var angular = angular.module('ngApp', ...
```

Try renaming `angular` variable to something else, like `app`.

Here is a plunker example of it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/t9KoqROnfWda8XsThOPE

Comment: its giving output `Hello {{msg}}` rather it must `Hello test message`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the plunker.

Comment: can you tell us what was the mistake and how you corrected it, i am in learning phase, Thanks.

Comment: Apparently something on plunker end has changed and link to Angular.js stopped working, so I've just readded angular to the plunk.

Answer (score -1):

Use same version of Angular and AngularRoute

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var myApp = angular.module('ngApp', ['ngRoute']);
    myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
          $routeProvider
             .when('/', {
               //....
})

})();
```

Comment: Nope. Same thing. (

Comment: @SamKirklandWA Have you tried naming your module something different than 'ngApp'?  Could be a used name by angular already.

Comment: Nope, still same thing. (

Comment: still a nope..thing same.avoid reserved word strictly use other naming

Comment: @marked the code posted is literally an example of the selected answer.  This post is well over two years old.